# Dúvidas no In App purchase Android

Tags: android, app, sharedpreferences

Eu tenho duas dúvidas no In App purchase...

Primeiro queria saber o que seria isso de esconder a key64 que fala na aplicação de teste que tem no Android Studio, porque não é recomendado deixar em uma `String` no código mesmo.

A segunda é que no caso, estou fazendo um jogo, e o que poderia comprar, seriam as moedas, mas como é **offline**, posso depois que confirmada a compra, simplesmente salvar no `Shared Preferences` a nova quantia de moedas?

Answer (score 0):

> Em relação a key64

Você deve deixar a chave publica **base64EncodedPublicKey** direto no código sendo gerada em tempo de execução ou recupera la de forma criptografado. Isso é necessário por medidas de segurança para evitar que um atacante mau intencionado á descubra.

> Após a compra

Sim pode salvar em shared preferences, porém não seria seguro. Visto que caso o aparelho tenha o **root** liberado o usuário conseguiria ver e até alterar os valores de *shared preferences*. 
Tente salvar os dados **criptografado** ou pelo menos salvar em banco de dados no **SQLite**